# Coordinates format in ArcGis 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

Regarding to [Jay suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/export-table-from-arcgis-to-exel-file/4158#4158) i open a new topic.

Do you know how i can set in arcgis 9.3 coordinates only with one locus after comma, i mean like that format: xx xx xx,x not like i have now xx xx xx,xxx (screen below)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in two different ways.

1. You can simply use the field calculator and recalculate the same field with the values mentioned in the other post. WARNING!! IF you do this outside of an edit session and on the same field you risk losing data if the caclulation doesn't evaluate correctly.
2. The better solution: set the coordinate system for the MXD document to WGS and the set the precision to DMS with the 0,00 in the seconds place. Right click on the dlugosc field and select caclulate geometry. 
   Take care to associate the correct value and system for each field.
   AGAIN WARNING!! you will be recalculating the actual location of these points and overwriting the values. If a point has moved it will reflect the new location value.

I see that this is not an excel (event) table so these values are not used to locate the points they are simply a record of the location (an external table with xy values does locate the point when formatted as an event table). You will see in the calculate geometry dialog that there are several choices for how to calculate. The units is determined by the CRS of the MXD you have open.

NOTE: to format an external table (XLS, DBF, MDB, CSV, TXT.) with xy values you select the table in the source tab of TOC and select Display XY Data. You would then select the coordinate system your data is in (usually going to be [geographic system WGS84]) lat lon.

Answer (score 2):

Within the MXD file right click on the point feature class and choose properties.  Next Select the fields tab.  You should now see a listing of all the fields associated with you feature class.  Find your fields dlugosc and szerokosc in the list.  If you click on the box with the ellipse under number formatting you can control how the numbers appear in both the table view as well as labels for each field independently.  Since this is done within the mxd it only applies to the current map document.  If you want to make this change permanently to the data set in question you will need to define a field with your parameters for number of significant zeros, etc and calculate the existing values from the existing to new field.