# Exporting list of street names from selection in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am trying to get a list of street names and ranges for a specific area of my map.  My intention is to make a street index of sorts from this data.  I would like to export this data into Excel if possible.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

I'm using ArcMap 9.3.

Answer (score 4):

Try to open the attribute table (right-click on layer and click the `Open Attribute Table` menu-item) and then copy/paste the selected records.

The first part of this answer takes care of the copy/paste steps:
[Exporting table from ArcGIS Desktop to Excel file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/export-table-from-arcgis-to-excel-file/4158#4158)

You can also export the selected records to text or dbf and open in excel.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have Microsoft Office installed, the following method has worked for me.

1. Create empty personal geodatabase (mdb)
2. Export selected features into this new, empty personal geodatabase.
3. Open up this personal geodatabase in MS Access, and the feature class created in step 2 should appear as a regular table.  You should be able to export this table directly to Excel, or any number of other formats.  You'll probably want to delete the geometry(SHAPE) column.