# Error exporting attribute table in ArcMap to Excel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, excel

I try to export an attribute (and dbf) table from ArcMap10 to txt file, but the program gives "An error occurred exporting the table"

I checked all others types of exporting - all give the same, except only dbf (so I can export attribute table only in dbf format).
What I did wrong?

My main goal now – find how to export the attribute table to Excel. Now I can’t do it. Also I can’t copy my table from ArcMap and put it to Excel (I read this way as an advice), I don’t know the reason, but it doesn’t work. Maybe this problem relates with this error that gives ArcMap? Could you help me, why ArcMap doesn't export attribute and dbf table to others format, except dbf format?

Comment: not sure what you mean exporting dbf to txt.  you have a dbf table in arcmap?

Comment: I want to know, after editing the excel table. Instead, is the tips could be implemented from excel to attributable ArcMap? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you open the attribute table,
open an empty excel spreadsheet,
Select all or some of the records in the attribute table.
to select all the button in upper left gives this pulldown to accomplish that.
[image: select all]

right click on the left edge (on a box).
[image: box]

copy selected.
Switch to the spreadsheet. right click in the upper left cell (just one cell)
ctrl+V (paste).

Comment: It works! Thank you! So, I just copied the table incorrectly.   Now I know how to solve my main task, but I steel have the error of exporting dbf table to txt and others formats. It's strange error.. Maybe I also did something incorrectly..