# Trying to export table from mxd using arcpy Copy Rows but get cannot create output error?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, error-000210

I am trying to export a table from a mxd using arcpy.  I need a comma delimited .txt file.  I believe the CopyRows_management function should work, however I always get a cannot create output error number 000210.

```
# new 6_ export script
import arcpy, os

finalFolder = r"C:\workspace\CRAI_outside_finalDeliv\SectionA"

# intermediate variables:
GISMXD = os.path.join(finalFolder, "4_ArcGIS_Map_Documents\SectionA.mxd")
folder6_hvl = os.path.join(finalFolder, "6_GPS_Horizontal_Vertical_Location")
txtFilePath = os.path.join(folder6_hvl, "SectionA_SiteMarker_WGS84_DD.txt")

GISMapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(GISMXD)
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(GISMapDoc)[0]
GsMPLay = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(DF)[0]
# I consistently get an error 000210 cannot create output on the next line.  Can't figure out why.
arcpy.CopyRows_management(GsMPLay, txtFilePath)

del DF
del GISMapDoc
```

Ultimately I want to be able to do something like what is done in this question: [Copy, not export, a table from Arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58939/copy-not-export-a-table-from-arcmap) but using arcpy.
The full error message is:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 15, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 15215, in CopyRows     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\workspace\CRAI_outside_finalDeliv\SectionA\6_GPS_Horizontal_Vertical_Location\SectionA_SiteMarker_WGS84_DD.txt Failed to execute (CopyRows).
```

I'm using Arc 10.3, python 2.7.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Security Essentials/Windows Defender?

Comment: Also, post your full error message.

Comment: What is your source layer that you wish to export?  Some data sources do not export well.  It may be an issue with the connection or permissions if it is a database table being exported.

Comment: I do have windows defender, but it hasn't been an issue before, it is pretty well configured.  I am exporting a point feature class in a geodatabase with domains; the point class is joined to a table in the same gdb.  I've edited the question with the full error message.

Answer (score 2):

To output a table to a text file, use TableToTable_conversion (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm).

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(GsMPLay, folder6_hvl, "SectionA_SiteMarker_WGS84_DD.txt")
```

Comment: I have never gotten table to table to convert to anything other than dbf tables, and a .txt is what I need.

Comment: If you specify the name of the output table as ".txt", it will be converted to a text file.

Comment: Even when I specify the output as a .txt, it comes out as a .dbf.  Example:

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(GsMPLay, r'C:\workspace\CRAI_outside_finalDeliv\RSNC_Section63A\6_GPS_Horizontal_Vertical_Location', "output2.txt")


<Result     'C:\\workspace\\CRAI_outside_finalDeliv\\RSNC_Section63A\\6_GPS_Horizontal_Vertical_Location\\output2.dbf'>

sorry for the bad formatting, I'm having difficutly configuring this.

Comment: That is strange. You might want to edit the question to highlight the specific issue of not being able to convert to a text file.  Have you tried the TableToTable_conversion on other layers/featureclasses with the same result? What happens when you try it with a text file as the input? Does it still convert it to a dbf? Can you export to a .txt successfully from the ArcMap attribute table?

Comment: I can export from an arcmap table to whatever format I want the normal way, I just can't do it with arcpy.  I've tried a variety of inputs with that tool, including xls, csv, shp, and feature classes with the same result of a dbf.