# Does ArcGIS Pro have an alternative to ArcMap's "Copy Selected" option for attribute tables?

Tags: attribute-table, export, arcgis-pro, copy

I'm in the process of trying to switch fully from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro (version 2.0). One small piece of functionality in ArcMap that I used very frequently was the "Copy Selected" option to copy selected rows from an attribute table into Excel. (See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58943/4681) if you don't know what I'm referring to.)

In ArcGIS Pro, I cannot find an analogous method to copy tabular data. The only method I can see is using the "Copy Rows" geoprocessing tool, which would majorly slow down my workflows.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered that the keyboard shortcut, `Ctrl + Shift + C`, provides this functionality in both ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro. As far as I can tell, there is no way to do it through the user interface, though.

Comment: Does it copy field names as well?

Comment: @FelixIP yes, it has the same behavior as "Copy Selected" in ArcMap

Comment: You might have to reselect from the selected rows (so they're yellow) before `ctrl-shift-c` works.